# Using Hudson to build RPM packages

Tags: hudson, rpm

I've a C project set up in Hudson doing nighly builds, i've also an .rpm spec file used for creating rpms from these sources.

Does anyone have any experience on how to build rpms out of all this using Hudson ?

Right now the only solution I see is to set up a job running a script that checks svn exports the sources ,creates a tarball and does the whole rpm build. This doesn't seem to integrate well with Hudson - e.g. how do I collect the artifacts ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I've got a very good answer to your question.

This has worked for me, but feels overweight for your needs.

I've had a decent amount of success with this by using the maven rpm plugin
http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/
basically a DSL for creating spec files, laying out sources, etc.

The upside is a maven artifact that hudson can more easily track.

I've added a little groovy script in the maven build (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code)  for my needs at the end to auto update a yum repository that hosts the builds, but in your situation, I'd probably use the script before the rpm plugin is used to call make.

Honestly, I feel the above solution is a bit weighty, mostly due to the verbosity of doing scripting in maven, but it does work, and for us, with a bunch of java developers who know maven, works well.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it for two projects now. It's not hard, but depends heavily on your workflow. The most important question is: what do you want to do with that package after it's been built? In my previous project, the package just went up to the repository, so that I didn't need to collect any artefacts.

Either way, a couple of hints from me:

1. You'll need a build area for Hudson/Jenkins, it can be just a directory in JENKINS_HOME. You need to point rpmbuild to it via `.rpmmacros`. Mine looks just like `%_topdir        /srv/build`, but you are of course free to define more macros there.
2. In my last project, I needed to build RPMs either from intergration branches (in the integration time frame) or from trunk (outside of integration time frame). For that, I've built a Perl script, which checked out the correct branch depending on current date and ran `rpmbuild -bb project.spec` on it. Since this script also uploaded the RPMs to the repository, I didn't need anything else besides this single script, meaning I actually used Hudson like an advanced cron manager (automatic build three times a day, manual builds on mouse click). It was still SVN-triggered though, so that we didn't build unnecessarily.
3. I wanted to have clean packages and also retain the possibility to build from command-line. For that reason, my RPM spec created its own tarball automatically from an SVN export. I've taken the exporting functionality out for current project, so it looks like this now:

   ```
   %define module my_project
   %define _curdir .
   %define _release %(/usr/bin/svnversion -c %_curdir | %__sed 's/.*://g')
   %define _moddir %module-%_version-%_release
   %define _source %(/bin/tar czf %_sourcedir/%_moddir.tar.gz --transform="s|^./|%_moddir/|g" --exclude=.svn .; /bin/echo %_moddir.tar.gz)
   ```

   and later in the spec:

   ```
   Source0: %_source
   ```
4. In my current project, I've split that script up into parts, so that my current Jenkins job only consists of `rpmbuild ...` command. The reason was that I didn't need to build from different branches.

In conclusion: building RPMs is possible via Jenkins, it's fairly easy, since the difficult part is making a clean RPM spec. Everything else depends on your needs, which are fixable with either a bit of scripting or with a Jenkins plugin.

Comment: How does that build-a-tarball script work when the RPM's then built independently outside the svn scaffoldng ?  

While it's a test that too many don't run, the ability to confirm an independent build is a very valuable one.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above - once you can create an RPM from any directory you can script up the build process and put it straight into Hudson.

Here's the magic:

```
rpmbuild --define '_topdir '`pwd` -ba SPECS/helloworld.spec
```

This sets the top level directory for the build process as the current directory.

I had the same problem and documented the full process at
http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/rpm-build-hudson-jenkins.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not done it myself but would think you could have Hudson build the rpms but with the rpm build area being within the Hudson workspace. Then you would be able to link to the rpms as artifacts.

[Here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html) is how you use a different build area with rpm.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as build tool on hudson? Make?

You can create a directory structure that rpm build will use in the Workspace of the Hudson Job - this can already be in the checkout that Hudson does, or it can be created separately by your build script. From this directory you can create your rpms (using an external process that you launch from Hudson?). Afterward you can copy the resulting rpm to the artifacts directory using the normal Hudson configure settings. (Hudson defines a number of [environment variables](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-HudsonSetEnvironmentVariables) that you can use - the workspace location is one of them)

Answer (score 1):

Ant can be used to build RPM's via the built-in RPM task.
You can compile C sources with Ant with the CC task (from Ant-contrib).

Then you can use Hudson to build and package our software.

Answer (score 1):

At one point, I replaced the maven dsl I mentioned above with a custom Scala plugin, in part just to learn scala.  It did meet some more needs than that.  But now, I'd just advocate using

fpm, which does a great job in 90% of the rpm creation needs (also does deb, et. al)

http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/fpm.html

project here:
https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Jenkins shell script we use:

```
export PROJECT_NAME=
export PROJECT_VERSION=

#Cleanup
rm -f /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/SPECS/$PROJECT_NAME.rpm.spec 
rm -Rf /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/SOURCES/$PROJECT_NAME /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES/$PROJECT_NAME

#Copy sources/artifacts
cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$PROJECT_NAME/workspace/project-set/$PROJECT_NAME/showme/include/$PROJECT_NAME.rpm.spec /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/SPECS/$PROJECT_NAME.rpm.spec
cp -R /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$PROJECT_NAME/workspace/project-set/$PROJECT_NAME/showme /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES/$PROJECT_NAME
cp -R /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$PROJECT_NAME/workspace/project-set/$PROJECT_NAME/showme /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/SOURCES/$PROJECT_NAME

#Build RPM
rpmbuild --define 'BUILD_NUMBER '$BUILD_NUMBER -ba /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/SPECS/$PROJECT_NAME.rpm.spec --define '_topdir '/tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/

cp /tmp/JENKINS-BUILD/RPMS/noarch/$PROJECT_NAME-$PROJECT_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER.noarch.rpm /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$PROJECT_NAME/workspace
```

(Credit to JT/JWT)

Answer (score 0):

after some research of information from many blogposts and other resources i merged this all into one script, which could be easyly used in jenkins for building packages: https://github.com/jhrcz/jenkins-rpm-builder.

it collects the artifacts (rpm packages) int the form of yum repository, so with some configuration, httpd could be directed to the latest stable build repo.

in the code you could find that it supports package signing and tries to solve all the differences needed betwen el5 and el6.